# Can echo size of SESSION?

Tags: php, session

I dont know if my sessions are too big. Is there a way to see the size of a session.
Thanks,
Rahul

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$size_of_session_estimate = strlen( serialize( $_SESSION ) );
```

Now, this is just an estimate, as the serialize handler is *not* used to serialize sessions, but it also won't be too far off.

That being said, unless you're storing a silly amount of data in the session, you probably don't need to worry about this.

Comment: I am curious, I thought the size limit of the session was based soley on your memory, is there other factors?  I ask because I store an insane amount of data in user sessions

Comment: I suppose this works because strlen gives number of characters. 
And each character is 1kb.. correct me if im wrong.

Comment: @Rahul - each character is one *byte*.

Comment: I don't think there is an actual size *limit* to the session, but it will take longer during session creation to unserialize if there's a large amount of data.

Comment: There will be two factors limiting session size: the amount of memory available to the individual script, and the amount of available space used to store the serialised session between requests (typically a temp file on disk in the case of Apache - although *nix will probably cache those in free memory).  It will be the former (php memory limit) that will run out first

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Apache, take a look into your `APACHE_ROOT/tmp` folder and look for files named `sess_***********`.

Otherwise take the script from [here](http://paste-it.net/public/f305f9c) and call it using `array_size($_SESSION)`. This might differ slightly from the exact value (depending on compression/optimizations done by your PHP module).

Comment: Keep in mind that some configurations may store sessions in places other than /tmp.  You'll need to examine your PHP configuration to be sure.

Comment: paste-it.net is offline, do you have an alternative link to your script?

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
echo strlen(session_encode());
```

will give you the amount of disk space used by $_SESSION (assuming *session.save_handler* is the default value *files*), since *session_encode()* returns a string identical to the string stored in the session file.

It will also give a better indication of the amount of memory used, since *session_encode()* adds less metadata than *serialize()*.

On a default Apache setup, you can see the session data as stored on disk with:

```
session_write_close();
echo file_get_contents(sys_get_temp_dir() . 'sess_' . session_id());
```